# stdio.h not standard in C++?

Tags: c++, stdio, standard-library

I know most compilers allow both:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

and

```
#include <cstdio>
```

But someone argued that `<stdio.h>` is not actually C++ standard.  Is that true?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`stdio.h` is standard, but deprecated. Always prefer `cstdio` in C++.

> `[n3290: C.3.1/1]:` For compatibility with the Standard C library, **the
>   C++ standard library provides the 18 C headers (D.5), but their use is
>   deprecated in C++.**
>
> `[n3290: D.5/3]:` [ *Example:* The header `<cstdlib>` assuredly
>   provides its declarations and definitions within the namespace `std`. It
>   may also provide these names within the global namespace. **The header
>   `<stdlib.h>` assuredly provides the same declarations and definitions
>   within the global namespace, much as in the C Standard. It may also
>   provide these names within the namespace `std`.** *—end example* ]

Comment: -1 the advice "Always prefer `cstdio` in C++" is ungood. `cstdio` does not guarantee a clean global namespace, so its only effect is that you have to write more qualifications or using statements or whatever to get portable code. I.e., it's more work for negative gain, which is as silly as possible => the advice is ungood.

Comment: @Alf: So you'd recommend deprecated headers? That seems silly. And `using`/qualifiers are _a good thing_.

Comment: no, that's an invalid generalization. however the C headers will not go away. C++ is dead long before that.

Comment: @Alf: No idea what you're talking about now.

Comment: in an international standard the term "deprecated" means "can be removed in a later version of the standard". however the C headers are not going to go away. they were optimistically deprecated in C++98, but AFAIK no implementation ever made the clean separation required by C++98, which is surely the reason why C++11 now allows the headers to pollute namespaces.

Comment: Your technical and historical analysis is accurate. But the headers are still deprecated and I see no reason to prefer them. If I see C headers in C++ code review, the code does not pass. End of.

Comment: As long as C and C++ compilers live together (most compilers have C and C++ mode) and use the same system include directory, the C headers will be there, even if they are removed from standard.

Comment: However, C header files can detect whether a C++ compiler is being used and in the future, such inclusion can result in a compiler error.

Answer (score 8):

It's not true, because C++ main goal is backward compatibility with C. The only difference is that for

```
#include <cstdio>
```

all functions are in `std` namespace

Comment: Bit of a simplistic view. `stdio.h` _may_ put things in `std`, and using it is deprecated anyway.

Comment: as long as C++ is going to be compatible with C it will be legal :D

Comment: But deprecated. And C++ is not 100% compatible with C of course.

Comment: "C++ main goal is backward compatibility" Do you have a reference? C++ isn't compatible with C in some noticeable way, e.g., empty function parameter list in C means unrestrained parameters but in C++ means no parameter.

Answer (score 3):

The C standard headers are included in the C++ standard library for compatibility.

The difference is that identifiers in corresponding C++ headers must (also) be in std namespace, whereas identifiers in C headers must (also) be available in global namespace.

In addition, the `<c...>` headers add overloads for functions like `abs`, `pow` etc.

Also, C++ headers replace some C classification/comparison macros with overloaded functions.

Comment: You may not be aware of it, but they are. And I quoted that passage from the standard quarter of an hour ago.

Comment: -1 "In addition" is wrong: C++11 §D.5/2 "Every C header, each of which has a name of the form `name.h`, behaves as if each name placed in the standard library namespace by the corresponding *cname* header is placed within the global namespace scope."

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: visitor was correct. Overloads for different input types for `abs` and similar functions are defined in `<cmath>` but not in `<math.h>` (which doesn't include `abs` at all; it's in `<stdlib.h>`, and only takes int.)

Comment: @Kundor: What's the very first word that you don't understand in  C++11 §D.5/2 "Every C header, each of which has a name of the form name.h, behaves as if each name placed in the standard library namespace by the corresponding cname header is placed within the global namespace scope."?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Well, my compiler doesn't understand it either, because what visitor and I said is what happens. Try it.

Comment: @Kundor: Report compiler bugs to the compiler vendor.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Both g++ and clang++ act as described. Neither `abs` nor `std::abs` are defined when including `math.h`. clang++ gives the more helpful error message "include the header <cmath> or explicitly provide a declaration for 'std::abs'" when you try to use `abs` from stdlib.h. So either the standard is not followed by major systems, in which case it is meaningless, or you have misunderstood it. It's also common that `<*.h>` headers define function-like macros, where the `<c*>` counterpart defines true functions.

Comment: @Kundor: clang was created as a drop-in replacement for g++, and has some of the same bugs. I haven't checked whether what you report are bugs, but if you want to check for C++11 the relevant overloads of `abs` are (1) `int`, `long` and `long long` provided by `<cstdlib>` in namespace `std` (plus possibly in the global namespace), and by `<stdlib.h>` in the global namespace (plus possibly in namespace `std`), and (2) `float`, `double` and `long double` provided by header `<cmath>` in namespace `std` (plus possibly in the global namespace) and by `<math.h>` in the global namespace (plus..)

Comment: This has nothing to do with the answer above, which is wrong. The C++ ".h" headers are *defined in terms of* the C++ "c..." headers, which in turn are defined in terms of the C ".h" headers (generally, but `<ccomplex>` is an exception). The crucial fact is C++ `<xxx.h>` is defined in terms of `<cxxx>`. It can't miss any overloads or have other arbitrary differences.

Comment: All that said, it *sounds* as if you erroneously expect some overload of `std::abs` to be guaranteed defined when you only include `<math.h>`. It doesn't guarantee that. It only guarantees to place it in the global namespace.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: No, like I said, neither `abs` nor `std::abs` is defined when including `<math.h>`; the various overloads are included only by `<cmath>`, as the error from clang explicitly says. On my system, which I do not think is abnormal, `<*.h>` directly includes the system C header, which is not part of the C++ library (which only provides the `<c*>` headers.)

Comment: Report the bug. Stop saying "no" to the ISO standard. The ISO standard is the standard. Any deviation from it, is non-conformance. Just report it and stop arguing. You can google SO to find references to where you can obtain drafts of the standard (there is a community wiki posting with a list somewhere, as I recall). You'll need that for your report. Relevant paras are §26.8 about the overloads, and §D5.2 quoted above about the headers in general.

Comment: Also, from the [libstdc++ docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_headers.html#manual.intro.using.headers.cheaders) about `<*.h>` vs `<c*>` headers: " the C++-style headers can use function overloading to provide a simpler interface to certain families of C-functions. For instance in <cmath>, the function std::sin has overloads for all the builtin floating-point types. This means that std::sin can be used uniformly, instead of a combination of std::sinf, std::sin, and std::sinl."

Answer (score -1):

The C++ standard library explicitly contains the C standard library, so  is an entirely legitimate part of C++. And if you are talking about using `#include <stdio.h>` in C++ code, then you shouldn't do that, cause that's C syntax, in C++ code, you should use always cstdio

Comment: It's not "C syntax" any more than `#include <cstdio>` is.

Comment: I know, but it's not so common to see someone use `#include <cstdio>` in C code

Comment: That's because `cstdio` doesn't exist in C... I think you might be misunderstanding the meaning of the word "syntax".

Comment: -1 the advice "you shouldn't do that" is ungood. cstdio does not guarantee a clean global namespace, so its only effect is that you have to write more qualifications or using statements or whatever to get portable code. I.e., it's more work for negative gain, which is as silly as possible => the advice is ungood.

Comment: @AlfP.Steinbach I never said he should use cstdio, but if he had to use either stdio.h or cstdio in C++ code, he should be using cstdio