# GoogleTest 1.6 with Cygwin 1.7 compile error: 'fileno' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, eclipse, cygwin, googletest

GoogleTest 1.6 with Cygwin 1.7: 'fileno' was not declared in this scope

Error message when building a simple test on Factorial() function in Eclipse CDT:

```
Invoking: Cygwin C++ Compiler
g++ -std=c++0x -DGTEST_OS_CYGWIN=1 -I"E:\source\gtest-1.6.0\include" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/challenge.d" -MT"src/challenge.d" -o "src/challenge.o" "../src/challenge.cpp"
In file included from E:\source\gtest-1.6.0\include/gtest/internal/gtest-internal.h:40:0,
                 from E:\source\gtest-1.6.0\include/gtest/gtest.h:57,
                 from ../src/challenge.cpp:11:
E:\source\gtest-1.6.0\include/gtest/internal/gtest-port.h: In function 'int testing::internal::posix::FileNo(FILE*)':
E:\source\gtest-1.6.0\include/gtest/internal/gtest-port.h:1589:51: error: 'fileno' was not declared in this scope
E:\source\gtest-1.6.0\include/gtest/internal/gtest-port.h:1595:57: error: 'strdup' was not declared in this scope
E:\source\gtest-1.6.0\include/gtest/internal/gtest-port.h:1627:71: error: 'fdopen' was not declared in this scope
```

Eclipse CDT 8.1 running gcc 4.7.3 on Cygwin 1.7.22

gTest 1.6 succesfully built including demo tests, with cmake 2.8.9 on Cygwin 1.7.22

I've linked the built lib with full path, E:\lib\gtest-1.6.0\Cygwin\libgtest.a

The following command option was added manually, got same error without it.

```
-DGTEST_OS_CYGWIN=1
```

Seems the errors have nothing to do with my code. Anyone using gTest with Eclipse and Cygwin?

Thank you,

```
unsigned long Factorial(unsigned n) {
    return n==0? 0 : n*Factorial(n-1);
}

// Tests factorial of 0.
TEST(FactorialTest, HandlesZeroInput) {
  EXPECT_EQ(1, Factorial(0));
}

// Tests factorial of positive numbers.
TEST(FactorialTest, HandlesPositiveInput) {
  EXPECT_EQ(1, Factorial(1));
  EXPECT_EQ(2, Factorial(2));
  EXPECT_EQ(6, Factorial(3));
  EXPECT_EQ(40320, Factorial(8));
}
```

Answer (score 22):

Setting the C++ standard to -std=gnu++0x rather than -std=c++0x, worked for me. You can  try the statement:

```
g++ -std=gnu++0x -DGTEST_OS_CYGWIN=1 -I"E:\source\gtest-1.6.0\include" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/challenge.d" -MT"src/challenge.d" -o "src/challenge.o" "../src/challenge.cpp"
```

Setting symbol (-DGTEST_OS_CYGWIN=1) has got nothing to do with this error.

Comment: I must say I also experimented with `GTEST_OS_CYGWIN` symbol (with same result, i.e. nothing). Probably this is because c++0x does not include posix.

Comment: This also works to solve a similar issue with QNX 6.6 Momentics 5.0 .

Answer (score 12):

Some functions go beyond the ANSI standard.
These are disabled when you use std=c++11 (or std=c++0x).

Among them are `fdopen`, `fileno` and `strdup`. 
There are two possibilities to use them:

- Use the GNU dialect (std=gnu++11).
- If you want to compile without dialect and make a local exception, you can include stdio.h with the __STRICT_ANSI__ undefined. (see: [Error "'fdopen' was not declared" found with g++ 4 that compiled with g++3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15944051/error-fdopen-was-not-declared-found-with-g-4-that-compiled-with-g3))

I have tested both on Suse Linux Enterprise 11, MinGW and Cygwin.

---

**Addition:** Another (possibly better) way to access non-ANSI symbols would be to add

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
```

**before the first #include in your file**. This will give you access to most of the non-standard routines.

Some functions (e.g. `realpath(...)`) require

```
#define _BSD_SOURCE
```

to be inserted on top of your file.