# error: ‘fileno’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, c++11, makefile

I am running Cygwin on windows 8, attempting to compile the source code for a game I would like to mod. Unfortunately I am running into some errors while building involving the fileno function. After doing some googling It seems like the problem might have to do with c++11 support (I'm not really sure what this means). Most of the solutions people have found involve adding some option like -std=c++0x or -std=c++11 when compiling, but my attempts to add the options into the makefile have been unsuccessful, and I don't know if that's whats causing the problem anyways. I'll include the code snippet that's throwing the error and a link to the makefile as it is quite large. Any advice you could give me would be great.

code that throws error:

```
    time_t file_modtime(FILE *f)
    {
        struct stat filestat;
        if (fstat(fileno(f), &filestat))
            return 0;

        return filestat.st_mtime;
    }
```

[Link to Makefile](https://github.com/guyht/crawl/blob/89a41073edcf728b881dd939bffba866495a0133/crawl-ref/source/Makefile)

it is being hosted on github

EDIT: After getting some advice I poked around the makefile and found five instances where the -std option was used, playing around with them hasn't changed anything. Is the problem with my Cygwin configuration? I installed the packages I was told I would need in the installation guide for the game I am building.

Comment: Have you `#include <cstdio>`?

Comment: yes <cstdio> is included

Comment: possible duplicate of [GoogleTest 1.6 with Cygwin 1.7 compile error: 'fileno' was not declared in this scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18784112/googletest-1-6-with-cygwin-1-7-compile-error-fileno-was-not-declared-in-this)

Comment: I looked at that one before posting, and tried adding the options it suggested, but was unsuccessful. I was hoping for some advice on how to either work around it or where in the makefile the option needs to go.

Comment: Most probably it is being set in lines 1563/1565 in your makefile. Hard to say for sure without being able to fetch all requirements.

Comment: Have you tried setting the standards to -std=gnu++0x ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Changing the `-std=c***` in your makefile to `-std=gnu++0x` should fix your problem.

If you don't know what `c++11` is you're most likely not using it anyway.

Also if you need `c++11` support you can also do: `-std=gnu++11` instead of `-std=gnu++0x`

Answer (score 2):

For windows...

`fileno()` is deprecated: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/posix-fileno?view=vs-2017

use `_fileno()` instead: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fileno?view=vs-2017

Comment: No, `fileno()` is **not** "deprecated".  It is [a standard POSIX function - and isn't going away any time soon](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fileno.html).  Microsoft "deprecates" all kinds of standard functions, [even including many like `fopen()` that are required to be available by the C standard itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14386/fopen-deprecated-warning).  The cynic in me says Microsoft created all these fake "deprecations" to fool people into writing non-portable code.

Comment: The first URL from Microsoft states: "This POSIX function is deprecated. Use the ISO C++ conformant _fileno instead.", and that is why I stated "For windows..." at the beginning of this answer, because this information is provided in the windows context and should not be taken out of context.  I suppose we can edit or delete this answer if its confusing and unhelpful?

Comment: In the case of `fileno()`, Microsoft can't claim POSIX compliance and then state `fileno()` is "deprecated" as `fileno()` hasn't been deprecated by POSIX.  Furthermore, Microsoft's "deprecation" of other functions violates the very ISO C++ they're trying to claim supports "deprecation" of `fileno()`.  `fopen()`, for example, is listed as a required C++ function under table 134 of the [C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf).

Comment: (cont) What's even worse about Microsoft's "deprecations" is that they offer alternative functions that are ["incomplete and conforms neither to C11 nor to the original TR 24731-1."](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1967.htm)  Microsoft uses those "deprecations" to push functions that "... cannot be considered conforming or portable."  Now you have more of the full context of Microsoft's "deprecations".