# execinfo.h missing when installing xgboost in Cygwin

Tags: python, c, gcc, cygwin, xgboost

I've follow the following tutorial in order to install xgboost python package within Cygwin64:

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/jfp/entry/Installing_XGBoost_For_Anaconda_on_Windows

But when executing the make in dmlc-core directory I get the following errors:

```
harrison4@mypc ~/xgboost/dmlc-core
$ mingw32-make -j4
g++ -c -O3 -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Iinclude  -std=c++0x -fPIC -DDMLC_USE_HDFS=0 -DDMLC_USE_S3=0 -DDMLC_USE_AZURE=0 -msse2 -o line_split.o src/io/line_split.cc
g++ -c -O3 -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Iinclude  -std=c++0x -fPIC -DDMLC_USE_HDFS=0 -DDMLC_USE_S3=0 -DDMLC_USE_AZURE=0 -msse2 -o recordio_split.o src/io/recordio_split.cc
g++ -c -O3 -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Iinclude  -std=c++0x -fPIC -DDMLC_USE_HDFS=0 -DDMLC_USE_S3=0 -DDMLC_USE_AZURE=0 -msse2 -o input_split_base.o src/io/input_split_base.cc
g++ -c -O3 -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Iinclude  -std=c++0x -fPIC -DDMLC_USE_HDFS=0 -DDMLC_USE_S3=0 -DDMLC_USE_AZURE=0 -msse2 -o io.o src/io.cc
src/io/line_split.cc:1:0: aviso: se descarta -fPIC para el objetivo (todo el código es independiente de posición)
 // Copyright by Contributors
 ^
src/io.cc:1:0: aviso: se descarta -fPIC para el objetivo (todo el código es independiente de posición)
 // Copyright by Contributors
 ^
src/io/input_split_base.cc:1:0: aviso: se descarta -fPIC para el objetivo (todo el código es independiente de posición)
 // Copyright by Contributors
 ^
src/io/recordio_split.cc:1:0: aviso: se descarta -fPIC para el objetivo (todo el código es independiente de posición)
 // Copyright by Contributors
 ^
In file included from include/dmlc/io.h:14:0,
                 from src/io/line_split.cc:2:
include/dmlc/./logging.h:18:22: error fatal: execinfo.h: No such file or directory
compilación terminada.
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'line_split.o' failed
mingw32-make: *** [line_split.o] Error 1
mingw32-make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
In file included from src/io/input_split_base.cc:2:0:
include/dmlc/logging.h:18:22: error fatal: execinfo.h: No such file or directory
compilación terminada.
In file included from include/dmlc/io.h:14:0,
                 from src/io.cc:4:
include/dmlc/./logging.h:18:22: error fatal: execinfo.h: No such file or directory
compilación terminada.
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'input_split_base.o' failed
mingw32-make: *** [input_split_base.o] Error 1
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'io.o' failed
mingw32-make: *** [io.o] Error 1
In file included from include/dmlc/./io.h:14:0,
                 from include/dmlc/recordio.h:12,
                 from src/io/recordio_split.cc:2:
include/dmlc/././logging.h:18:22: error fatal: execinfo.h: No such file or directory
compilación terminada.
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'recordio_split.o' failed
mingw32-make: *** [recordio_split.o] Error 1
```

Why am I getting this error? Let me know if you need more information, please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can put `#undef DMLC_LOG_STACK_TRACE` right after it's definition on line 45 [here](https://github.com/dmlc/dmlc-core/blob/29b0cbdeaa8ce5ed843bcdaf1edf42cb8952bba7/include/dmlc/base.h#L45). See example in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/vkotovv/0eb1e50d7e9dfef05e528bbafce8173a).

`execinfo.h` is only available on Linux, but in this project it is used only for debugging and printing stack trace on Linux. There is [a check](https://github.com/dmlc/dmlc-core/blob/29b0cbdeaa8ce5ed843bcdaf1edf42cb8952bba7/include/dmlc/base.h#L40) for Mingw in their codebase, don't know why it is not defined (they've disabled it, see this [PR](https://github.com/dmlc/dmlc-core/pull/205)).

You should try to change those lines and run `make` again.

Comment: Thanks! I tried removing those lines, but know I get the following error: https://pastebin.com/WSirnMNE

Comment: Oh, I see. Could you please return logging.h to it's original state and put `#undef DMLC_LOG_STACK_TRACE` right after it's definition on line 45 [here](https://github.com/dmlc/dmlc-core/blob/29b0cbdeaa8ce5ed843bcdaf1edf42cb8952bba7/include/dmlc/base.h#L45)? See example in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/vkotovv/0eb1e50d7e9dfef05e528bbafce8173a). I'm pretty sure it should work this way.

Comment: I could try it by myself, but I don't have a Windows machine right now. Maybe tomorrow I could try to build this stuff..

Comment: Ok, stack trace errors are gone. Now try to replace references to `fopen64` with `fopen` in your `src/io/single_file_split.h`. Also please change the `-std=c++0x` in your [Makefile](https://github.com/dmlc/dmlc-core/blob/master/Makefile) to `-std=gnu++0x` (there is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29692136/error-fileno-was-not-declared-in-this-scope) with similar problem).

Comment: Perfect! Now I was able to compile it, but I get the following error when installing the setup.py: https://pastebin.com/4n8KpgXV I've searched for this .so by this way: `find / -name "*libxgboost*"` but it doesn't retrieve nothing. (we're near!)

Comment: I will try to compile the whole thing tomorrow on Windows and get back to you

Comment: I looks like you did not successfully compile `libxgboost.so`. I've tried all these steps on my Ubuntu, and now I have this `so` in `[path to project]/xgboost/lib` dir. But I had to run the latest `make` **twice** - it had some errors on my 1st run.

Comment: Thanks again! I tried the following steps: https://pastebin.com/XAijBFU5

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145212/discussion-between-vadim-kotov-and-harrison4).