# Include library from different standard

Tags: c++

Say I want to compile a project with -std=c++0x, but I want a library such as stdio.h to be included from anything pre-c++0x.  It seems functions like fdopen are not available in c++0x.

Is it possible to include a C++ library from an earlier standard?

Comment: Including a header file != including a library. The header file is going to get parsed by the compiler using the standard that you're compiling with. This sounds like an XY problem. If your issue is that you want to use fdopen when using C++11, then ask a question about *that*. (Oh, turns out you don't have to. Someone already did, and Zekian found it.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15944051/error-fdopen-was-not-declared-found-with-g-4-that-compiled-with-g3