# Adding a pointer to a string in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

I am confused with const pointers in C++ and wrote a small application to see what the output would be.  I am attempting (I believe) to add a pointer to a string, which should not work correctly, but when I run the program I correctly get "hello world".  Can anyone help me figure out what how this line (s += s2) is working?

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

const char* append(const char* s1, const char* s2){
    std::string s(s1);     //this will copy the characters in s1
    s += s2;               //add s and s2, store the result in s (shouldn't work?)
    return s.c_str();      //return result to be printed
}

int main() {
    const char* total = append("hello", "world");
    printf("%s", total);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `stdio.h` is deprecated in C++. Use `cstdio`. Anyway, you have [undefined behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope).

Comment: You're effectively returning a pointer/reference to a local variable, which is undefined behavior

Comment: you are returning a pointer to a local variable (undefined behavior).

Comment: It uses the operator function `operator+(std::string&, const char*)`.

Comment: Why do you think `s += s2;` shouldn't work? What shouldn't work is `return s.c_str();` because it returns a pointer into an object that no longer exists when the caller gets it.

Comment: @chris: This advice is debatable. I know of experienced C++ programmers who continue to use the old headers, whereas others argue for the new ones (just look at related past SO questions).

Comment: @ChristianHackl, They're officially deprecated per the standard. I prefer not to use deprecated things when there is no more functionality in them than in the newer ones. They buy you unoverloaded functions all in the global namespace.

Comment: In general, adding pointers is not a good idea and usually doesn't make sense (Add your home address to your friends's address, as they behave like pointers).  However, scalar quantities can be added to a pointer (My friend lives 3 houses south of my home).

Comment: @chris: I know that they are officially deprecated. But that doesn't mean the decision was wise. Errare humanum est. I don't want to repeat all arguments in a short comment, but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7596406/stdio-h-not-standard-in-c contains some good points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable `s` is local inside the `append` function. Once the `append` function returns that variable is destructed, leaving you with a pointer to a string that no longer exists. Using this pointer leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

My tip to you on how to solve this: Use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) all the way!

Answer (score 0):

you're adding `const char*` pointer to a `std::string` and that is possible (see [this reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator+=/)). it wouldn't be possible to make that operation on `char*` type (C style string).
however, you're returning a pointer to local variable, so once function `append` returns and gets popped of the stack, the string that your returned pointer is pointing to would not exist. this leads to an undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Class std::string has overloaded `operator +=`  for an operand of type `const char *`

```
basic_string& operator+=(const charT* s);
```

In fact it simply appends the string pointed to by this pointer to the contents of the object of type std::string allocating additionly memory if required. For example internally the overloaded operator could use standard C function `strcat`
Conceptually it is similar to the following code snippet.

```
char s[12] = "Hello ";
const char *s2 = "World";

std::strcat( s, s2 );
```

Take into account that your program has undefined behaviour because `total` will be invalid after destroying local object s after exiting function append. So the next statemnent in main

```
printf("%s", total);
```

can result in undefined behaviour.