# How does C++ process this

Tags: c++, c

I have here an equation i can't understand how c++ process this. Can someone explain this operation?

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

    main(){
        int a[10] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
        int i = 0;
        int num = a[i+++a[++i]]+a[++i+i++];
        printf("\nnum1: %d i: %d,num,i);
    }
```

why is the answer num = 9 while index i is just equal to 4;

Comment: Oh my, you have both [maximal munch](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5341202/1708801) and [undefined behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/q/949433/1708801) issues here. There is also no C++ here.

Comment: Drop that crappy line of code in favor of something a human can read and make sense of without spending an hour on how operator precedence, sequence points, and undefined behavior come into play in evaluating that line.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour I agree with your other points, but why it is not C++, is it not valid , C and C++?

Comment: It is valid C++.  `printf` is valid C++.  It is not stylistically good C++ and it is using a C++ method that is discouraged by nearly everybody, but `printf` is part of the C++ standard and so saying that it is "not C++" is just plain wrong.

Comment: @StevenBurnap Implicit int, however, has never been C++.

Comment: Ok, you're right, I missed that.

Comment: the C compiler always takes the longest token 
    which determines which '+'s go with which variable
    and C/C++ evaluate expressions per the rules listed in: 
    <http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence>

Comment: the C++ headers do not have a '.h' extension, so this is strictly C.

Comment: main() always returns an int, not a 'unknown' or 'void'

Comment: stdio.h is deprecated, but standard.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7596406/stdio-h-not-standard-in-c  Also, leaving out the return statement in main is legal in standard C++. (But as mentioned before, it must be declared `int`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `++` twice in the same expression on the same variable is explicitly undefined by all versions of both the C and C++ standards, and so `i` does not necessarily equal `4`.  It could be anything at the whim of the compiler writer.

Never do this.  Never use `++` and `--` twice in the same expression.  There is no way to make any statement about what the resultant value will be, and no experience with what it does with one compiler will mean anything with respect to what another compiler does.

Comment: I need to know what happen. why does c++ successfully compile and execute this code if it is undefined. it is given to us by our trainor to trace what is happenning in this code. so what does really happen?

Comment: Both C and C++ successfully compile lots of undefined things.  "Undefined" does not mean "won't compile".  It means "what happens if you do this is undefined".  If someone purporting to be teaching either C or C++ gave you this as something worth attempting to evaluate, then I'd have grave doubts as to their quality as a teacher.

Comment: (And I cannot tell you what will really happen because it entirely depends on what compiler you are using, in a way that is certainly not documented by the compiler writers.)