# Does the C++ standard require `#include <math.h>` to define the `abs` overloads found in `<cmath>`?

Tags: c++, std, math.h

The C++ standard defines some overloaded functions in the `<cmath>` header that are not part of the `<math.h>` header in C (because C doesn't have overloading).
Among these are `float abs(float)`, `double abs(double)`, `long double abs(long double)`, and `double abs(Integral)`.
On the other hand, `abs` is not defined in the C `<math.h>` at all (it is in `<stdlib.h>` instead) and the only signature is `int abs(int)`.

Now on my systems, when using a C++ compiler with a C++ program, `#include <math.h>` does not provide the C++ `abs` overloads, either in the global namespace or in `std`.
On the other hand, `#include <cmath>` defines `std::abs`.

This is what I'd expect—include the C version to get the C functions, and include the C++ version to get the C++ functions. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7596625/2132213) by @visitor mentions the same thing.

However, user @Cheers-and-hth-Alf insists that this is a violation of the standard, because it says "Every C header, each of which has a name of the form `name.h`, behaves as if each name placed in the standard library namespace by the corresponding *cname* header is placed within the global namespace scope." (This section, D.5.2, doesn't seem to have changed significantly between C++03, C++11, and C++14.)

It's easy enough to check what your platform does: see what happens with

```
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    abs(1.2);
    return 0;
}
```

If `abs` is not declared, then `<math.h>` does not include C++ functions.

If it compiles, then try including `<stdio.h>`
and add `printf("%g\n", abs(1.2));`
If this complains about a mismatched format, or prints 1, then `<math.h>`
includes the C `int abs(int)` function (normally in `<stdlib.h>`).
(It's best to avoid `<iostream>` and other C++ headers since they tend to pull in `<cstdlib>` and confuse the issue.)

Here's what I've found:

#### GNU libstdc++

```
$ g++ -Wall -Wextra abs2.cc -o abs2
abs2.cc: In function 'int main()':
abs2.cc:5:22: error: 'abs' was not declared in this scope
  std::cout << abs(1.2) << '\n';
```

The [libstdc++ docs on the subject](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_headers.html#manual.intro.using.headers.cheaders)
recommend including C++-style headers `<c*>` rather than C-style headers `<*.h>` precisely because
C++-style headers use function overloading, and the C-style headers do not.

#### Apple libc++

```
$ clang++ -Wall -Wextra abs2.cc -o abs2
abs2.cc:4:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'abs'; did you mean 'fabs'?
```

Additionally, if you also include `<stdlib.h>` to get a definition of `abs`, clang++ gives
the more helpful error message

```
abs2.cc:5:5: warning: using integer absolute value function 'abs' when argument is of floating point type [-Wabsolute-value]
    abs(1.2);
    ^
abs2.cc:5:5: note: use function 'std::abs' instead
    abs(1.2);
    ^~~
    std::abs
abs2.cc:5:5: note: include the header <cmath> or explicitly provide a declaration for 'std::abs'
abs2.cc:5:9: warning: implicit conversion from 'double' to 'int' changes value from 1.2 to 1 [-Wliteral-conversion]
    abs(1.2);
    ~~~ ^~~
abs2.cc:5:5: warning: ignoring return value of function declared with const attribute [-Wunused-value]
    abs(1.2);
    ^~~ ~~~
```

This explicitly says that the float overloads are only available from `<cmath>`, not from the
C traditional headers.

#### Apache libstdcxx

I didn't install it, but examining the [math.h header](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/stdcxx/trunk/include/ansi/math.h?view=markup), it brings those functions from `<cmath>` which are also defined in C's `<math.h>` into the global namespace, but does not include `abs`.

#### OpenWatcom C++

Again, examining the [cmath/math.h header](https://github.com/open-watcom/open-watcom-v2/blob/c8032600d2aa7fffd916452ae528b31e51d840fa/bld/hdr/watcom/math.mh),
when used as `math.h` it brings the same functions into the global namespace as Apache libstdcxx did, not including `abs`.

#### STLPort

Examining the [math.h header](https://sourceforge.net/p/stlport/code/ci/master/tree/stlport/math.h), it includes the system's C `<math.h>` header, which is not part of the C++ library and so doesn't include `abs`. (This is also what g++ and clang++ did.)

#### Microsoft Visual Studio (Dinkumware)

I don't have access to this myself,
but [this site](http://rextester.com/VPDG81796) claims to compile using Visual C++,
and it says

```
error C4578: 'abs': conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data
(Did you mean to call 'fabs' or to #include <cmath>?)
```

So, is literally *every* major C++ standard library implementation
in violation of the standard on this point?

Or are we missing something that the standard says about `<math.h>` and other traditional C headers?

Comment: An interesting and related reading from @JonathanWakely: http://developers.redhat.com/blog/2016/02/29/why-cstdlib-is-more-complicated-than-you-might-think/

Comment: @myaut Indeed, very relevant! It sounds like GCC 6 should be the first platform where `#include <math.h>` brings in the `abs` overloads. I will check it out. To be honest, I prefer the notion that `<cxxx>` brings C++-style overloads and `<xxx.h>` directly includes the system C header, if you want that.

Comment: Yes, it works: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/jxEYMKonFBkJiaeH

Answer (score 2):

***"Every C header, each of which has a name of the form name.h, behaves as if each name placed in the standard library namespace by the corresponding cname header is placed within the global namespace scope."***

That wording, to me, does not say that every name in the `<cname>` header must appear in the `name.h` header.

It says that every name in the `<name.h>` header ***that has a corresponding name*** in the `<cname>` header must appear in the global namespace.

It says nothing about names in the `<cname>` header that do not appear in the `<name.h>` header.

> **C++14** Stadard
>
> **D.5** C standard library headers **[** depr.c.headers **]**
>
> For compatibility with the C standard library and the C Unicode TR, the C ++ standard library provides **the 26 C headers**, as shown in Table

This statement uses the term "the 26 C headers" suggesting that they contain what the C Standard says they should contain, not what the `C++` Standard says that `<cname>` should contain.

Indeed, regarding `<cstddef>`, for example, it details things *not contained* in the corresponding `C` header.

**eg**

> **18.2 Types** **[** support.types **]**
>
> **2** The contents are the same as the Standard C library header `<stddef.h>`, with the following changes...

Comment: Also, it says **name**, not "overload".  `abs` is a name. Placing `abs` in the global namespace (without declaring the additional overloads) complies with this requirement