# Why am I not getting the remainder for “m”?

Tags: c

The input is number of months and the two outputs are years and months. If I type 18 months should give me 
Years 1
Months 6

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
    int y, m;

    printf("Input number of months: ");
    scanf_s("%i", &y);
    y = (int) y / 12
    m = (int)y %;

    printf(" %i Year(s) \n %i Month(s)", y, m);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are you trying to compile this exact code, with `Int` instead of `int`, with `“”` instead of `""`, and so on?

Comment: You're also missing a semicolon, and the line `m = (int) y %;` is nonsensical. How is this compiling

Comment: This doesn't compile does it?  In `m = (int)y %;` the % is a binary operator meaning it requires two operands (one on each side of the %)  Did you actually mean `m = (int)y % 12;` ?  Plus, you don't need either of the casts - division of integers produces an integer result (and so does mod)

Comment: Please post the **exact** code that you're having trouble with.  Don't attempt to retype it, but cut-and-paste the actual code.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah It wouldn't compile according to C++ standard, only possible using some compiler extensions (allowing C headers to be used). Although... Yeah I don't know any compiler which wouldn't accept C headers in C++ code

Comment: @Yksisarvinen  I have never seen anyone ever mention that before.  Even the C++ standard website says you can do it: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/mixing-c-and-cpp#include-c-hdrs-system

Comment: @JerryJeremiah I suppose I took "deprecated" for "disallowed", but you are right, it should compile with any C++ compiler. Though it's unusual for `isocpp.org` to be mistaken, perhaps it was actually un-deprecated in newer standard? [stdio.h not standard in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7596406/stdio-h-not-standard-in-c)

Comment: @Yksisarvinen  Fair enough - I concur.  Deprecated is not standard.

Comment: So when I run the program and I Input the number of months it gives me the same value for y and m. So like if I type 18 months it gives me Year 1 Month 1. Instead of Year 1 Months 6. 
I guess the issue is with m but again I’m not sure exactly what :(

Comment: @jeanluc what do you mean? Where am I missing the colon T_T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, this is the one closest to your own code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int y, m;

    printf("Input number of months: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%d", &y);
    m = y % 12;
    y = y / 12;

    printf(" %i Year(s) \n %i Month(s)" , y, m);
    return 0;
}
```

The key issue is that you updated the value of `y` before `m` had a chance to look at it. Note the order of your `y=...` and `m=...`. If you do `y=y/12` first, that would update `y`'s value to the number of years and the remainder information is lost at this step and `m` would always be 0. By getting `m` from the `y` that's from the user's input first, you avoid that issue.

Another minor issue is that there is no need to cast the value from `y/12` to be `int` since you are assigning that value to `y` which is of type `int` in the first place. Same applies to when you calculate `m`, where a typo is also present.

As for the use of `fflush`, you can refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin) for details. Compile your code with/without this line to see the difference.

Comment: More logical too to store input total month in `m` instead of `y`.

Comment: @Jarod42 true, but I thought to keep my answer as close to the question as possible so that the key issue stands out.

Comment: I didn’t see your answer until now @B.Gao ! I think I understand now I guess I was too focus on the output for m. On my way home I’ll try it as soon as I get there and I’ll let you know!! :D